# Select only colnames that end with a given pattern (in R)

Tags: r

I have a matrix where the names of columns have the following pattern:

`CATTGCCAGTTGAAAC.G_s1_6` 
`CGTTGCCACTTGAAAC.H_s1_1`

I would like to select only columns that finish with "G_s1_6".

Answer (score 2):

dplyr has a convenient `ends_with()` function for use inside `select()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(CATTGCCAGTTGAAAC.G_s1_6 = 1, CGTTGCCACTTGAAAC.H_s1_1 = 2)
df %>% select(ends_with('G_s1_6'))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  CATTGCCAGTTGAAAC.G_s1_6
                    <dbl>
1                       1
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R use a simple `grep`:

```
df <- data.frame(CATTGCCAGTTGAAAC.G_s1_6 = 1:5,
                 CGTTGCCACTTGAAAC.H_s1_1 = 2:6)

df[grep("G_s1_6", colnames(df))]

#  CATTGCCAGTTGAAAC.G_s1_6
#1                       1
#2                       2
#3                       3
#4                       4
#5                       5
```